# innerhtml submit button

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, innerhtml

#### What I am trying to do

I am using a `<form>` to research an address to eventually display it on Google maps.

After an initial input by the user, I refer them to a `search.php` page where the address parameters are separated into their components (i.e. Postal code, city), which are `<input type="text" readonly>` . There is also a Google map in which the address is displayed, and the user is asked if the displayed address is correct. They have a choice between `Yes` or `No`.

If the address is judged to be incorrect, they click on a `No` button which makes the various `<input type="text">` modifiable (removed the `readonly` attribute).

Once they click `No`, the `<div>` containing the submit buttons is accessed via `document.getElementById.innerHTML` and the buttons `Yes` and `No` are transformed into a single new `<input type="submit" value="Look it up">` button.

#### My problem!

This new `Look it up` button does not serve as a submit button!! Nothing happens when I click it.

Help please?

#### Code:

My reset function:

```
function reset_search() {
  document.getElementById('number').removeAttribute("readonly");
  document.getElementById('street').removeAttribute("readonly");
  document.getElementById('apt').removeAttribute("readonly");
  document.getElementById('postal').removeAttribute("readonly");
  document.getElementById('city').removeAttribute("readonly");

  document.getElementById('lookup').setAttribute('action', './search.php');
  var new_submit = 'Please correct the mistakes above and click on the button below to launch another search<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Look it up">';
  document.getElementById('submit_button').innerHTML=new_submit;
}
```

My form:

```
<form method="post" id="lookup" name="lookup" action="./display.php">
.........
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" colspan="4">
    <div id="submit_button">
    According to the map below, is the address correct?<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Yes" />&nbsp;<input type="button" value="No" onclick="reset_search()" />
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at your modified source code carefully after it is changed using debugger.
As long as submit button is inside form it submits the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/VC6XJ/

```
<form action="foo">
    <input type="submit" onclick="alert(this.form)" />
</form>
    <input type="submit" onclick="alert(this.form)"/>
<form action="bar">
    <input type="submit" onclick="alert(this.form)" />
</form>
```

As I experimented here, add onclick="alert(this.form)" to your submit button.

If it shows FormElement, and do nothing, it is big problem in w3c standard.

If it shows null, and do nothing, your submit button is outside of the form.

Comment: Thank you for that. Indeed, it appears that it is outside the form. However, as you can see in my code above, the <div> tag is inside the <form>, so how can that be possible?

Comment: I can't tell all possibilities unless i see your code. You might have include another form like this, http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/VC6XJ/1/, or you might have closed form before submit button.